# Equivalency two norms?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Suppose that the following norms on $C^1[0,1]$ . Are they equivalent norms?

$\|f\|=\|f\|_\infty+\|f'\|_\infty$ and $\|f\|=\max\{\|f\|_\infty, \|f'\|_\infty\}$ such that $f\in C^1[0,1]$ ,
 $\|f\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|$ .

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\max (a,b)\le a+b\le 2\max(a,b).$$

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent, owing to this inequality
$${a + b\over 2}\le \max(a,b) <= a + b $$

Answer (score 0):

In general, any two norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent.

How does that help here?

Consider two norms on $\mathbb{R}^2$: Let $n_1(x)=|x_1|+|x_2|$, $n_\infty(x)=\max(|x_1|,|x_2|)$. Since they are equivalent, we have constants $a,b$ such that $n_1(x) \le a n_\infty(x)$ and $n_\infty(x) \le b n_1(x)$.

Let $\|\cdot\|_a, \|\cdot\|_b$ be the two norms in the question.

It should be clear that $\|f\|_a = n_1(\|f\|_\infty, \|f'\|)$, and $\|f\|_b = n_\infty(\|f\|_\infty, \|f'\|)$. Then the equivalence of these two norms follows immediately from the equivalence of $n_1,n_\infty$.